# Equivalent group representations commutative diagram

Tags: representation-theory

[image]

I am confused by the commutative diagram displayed above. Why is $\varphi:V \to V$ and not $G \to GL(V)$? Analogous question for the mapping $\psi: W \to W$.

Comment: In the picture, the map is $\phi_g: V \rightarrow V$ where $\phi_g$ denotes the linear map $\phi(g)$. For a fixed group element $g$, the given diagram commutes.

Comment: What text is that from?it looks familiar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The horizontal maps are not $\varphi$ and $\psi$, but $\varphi_g$ and $\psi_g$ for some particular $g\in G$.  That is, the top horizontal map $\varphi_g$ is the image of $g$ under the homomorphism $\varphi$ (more commonly written $\varphi(g)$), which is a linear isomorphism $V\to V$, and similarly for $\psi_g$.

Answer (score 2):

$\varphi$ is a mapping from the representation $G$ to the general linear group of $V$. $\varphi_g $ is probably shorthand to represent $\varphi(g) $ for $g \in G $. $\varphi(g) $ is an element of $GL(V) $, and therefore an isomorphism from $V$ to $V$.